# jQuery Plugin select thead with "this" element

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

If I had two html tables like so:

```
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>Discount</th>
      <th>Difference</th>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Peter</td>
      <td>Parker</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>$9.99</td>
      <td>20.9%</td>
      <td>+12.1</td>
      <td>Jul 6, 2006 8:14 AM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Hood</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>$19.99</td>
      <td>25%</td>
      <td>+12</td>
      <td>Dec 10, 2002 5:14 AM</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br/><br/>
<table id="anotherTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>High Score</th>
      <th>Total Score</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Clark</td>
      <td>Kent</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>32</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bruce</td>
      <td>Almighty</td>
      <td>45</td>
      <td>180</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery on my HTML page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myTable").myplugin();
});
```

I am creating a jQuery plugin which I want to be able to apply to any or all HTML tables on a page in my application with either $("table").myplugin() or $("#myTable").myplugin().

in my plugin code:

```
return this.each(function(index){
    // code here
});
```

If I add the line `$(this).addClass('myClass')` the CSS "myClass" is added to table "myTable" but if I add the line `$('thead').addClass()` "myClass" is added to both theads.  I've tried `$(this thead).addClass(), $(this 'thead').addClass(), $('this thead').addClass()` but the all throw a JS error.  How do I utilize "this" to select only the thead in element "myplugin" is being applied to in this case "myTable"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`.find` method<sup>[jQuery docs]</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

```
$(this).find("thead").addClass();
```

If you are certain that `thead` is an immediate child of `this`, you can use [`.children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) instead and it would be faster, especially if you have very large tables.

```
$(this).children("thead").addClass();
```

You could also set `this` as the context for your query:

```
$("thead", this).addClass();
```

Comment: Ahhh, $('thead', this).addClass(); is just what I was looking for.  I was trying to avoid using $(this).find("thead") at this point since later in my code I will want to add a different class for th.  So I'm on the right page I should be able to do this: $('thead', this).find("th").addClass(); ?

Comment: Yes. You could also chain `.find`s: `$(this).find("thead").find("th")`.

Comment: I did read that plugins return the jquery object for chaining.  I'm not sure what I did earlier but it didn't work correctly.  However, I like $('thead', this).find() since it just looks cleaner in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
    $(this).find("thead").addClass("myClass");